# E325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"

Tags: git, github

I've been working with a team for almost a year now. It's always been easy to use github/git to pull and push changes using:

```
git pull
git add .
git commit -a -m "my work desc"
git push
```

That has always worked fine until recently. Now no matter what, if someone else has pushed, whenever I try to pull I get this message:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
          owned by: X   dated: Wed Jan 23 16:01:06 2013
         file name: ~X/Sites/mysite/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
          modified: no
         user name: X   host name: X-2.local
        process ID: 77109
While opening file ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
             dated: Thu Jan 24 16:22:48 2013
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.
    If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
    different instances of the same file when making changes.
    Quit, or continue with caution.

(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

This happens every time w/o fail. I can eventually get past this by inserting a message, saving and recommitting but it's a pain. Any idea why this keeps happening and what can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Do you do all your commits without `m` flag?

Comment: Do you get this message when you pull, or when you commit after pulling?

Comment: No, but how are you closing `vim` after you've typed your commit message?

Comment: If you have a swap file existing, vim will not delete it until you actually ask it to. Does choosing the `(D)elete it` option help?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unless you need **.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp** for some other purpose, you can use:

```
git rm .git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp
```

to remove the file from the repository.

Comment: Just press d in powershell to delete the file. That's generated by accidental changes to Vimdiff viewer.

Comment: Actually, it's `rm` not `git rm`.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem and for some reason using `git rm` didn't work for me.

To solve the problem, I simply removed the file instead: `$ rm .git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I had exactly the same situation and this helped me solve the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried deleting the message but it fails and complained that I do not have such file. So, I added a commit Message `-m` when doing `git commit -m` and the warning doesn't show any more .

Answer (score 1):

> You just need to press the "**d**" from the keyboard to remove the message.

**Steps:**

- Type "**git commit**"
- The "**E325: ATTENTION**" message will be displayed.
- Press the "**d**" button on the keyboard.

This will remove the issue and you will be able to commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to commit the changes if after a merge from another branch you this swap error message. I git added - green files not committed. I committed the files - then done.