# why git rebase --continue shows error for COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp file already exists?

Tags: git

I have master branch let's say m and feature branch f. After some commits in feature branch now I want to rebase mater branch into my feature branch. Following is the sequence of the commands I followed

1. git checkout m
2. git pull
3. git checkout f
4. git rebase m
   Now I got conflicts in one file which I resolved manually and then fired command
5. git add <conflicted_file>
6. git rebase --continue

After firing this command it shows error as COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp already exists!
I am not able to understand what action should I take for .swp file. Editor shows different options like
Q for quit, E for edit anyway, A for abort, R for recover
Can anyone explain which action I should take?

Comment: *Git* is not complaining here. *Vim* is complaining. It's still worth figuring out what is going on, but you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Git is not complaining but file is used by git. If I quit then whether subsequent actions will perform correctly?

Comment: https://engineering.purdue.edu/ece264/16au/resources/vim_swap_warnings `but file is used by git` it isn't, it's used by vim. Do you have another `git rebase` editor running? How did you exit the last editor?

Comment: BTW, concerning your initial sentence: Git doesn't have "master" or "feature" branches, that is just a common convention maintained by people using git. In consequence, git will never behave differently depending on whether it operates on a master or feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

> If I quit then whether subsequent actions will perform correctly?

I would try to edit anyway.

You should see an error like:

```
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
          owned by: X   dated: Wed Jan 23 16:01:06 2013
         file name: ~X/Sites/mysite/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
          modified: no
         user name: X   host name: X-2.local
        process ID: 77109
```

Check the process ID/owner associated to that file to understand where it is coming from.

And after the rebase, I would check if `.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp` is still there and, if yes, [delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35611644/6309).